# onValueChange of RN Picker getting called at first render when running via appium

Tags: react-native, appium, appium-android

**Problem**
I am using @react-native-community/picker to create one picker field and it has one callback function called onValueChange which gets called when some value is selected. Now, when I am running my app normally of my android device, at the first render, onValueChange is not triggered. But when I am running my app through Appium, onValueChange gets called on first render.
This will cause infinite render if some function is used to called setState in parent element. Am I doing something wrong in the code or Appium side?

**Environment:**
OS -> macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6 (17G14019)
Appium: 1.17.1-1
React Native: 0.61.2
Picker version: 1.6.6
Node: 10.14.2
Npm: 6.4.1

**Reproducing the problem**
Install @react-native-community/picker in dummy react native project.
after the write the code bellow in app.js
The console log doesn't log anything on the first render when app is running normally. But it logs the string on first render when app is running via appium.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Picker} from '@react-native-community/picker';
const app = () => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState('')
  return (
    <Picker
      selectedValue={language}
      style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
      console.log('on change called')
      setLanguage(itemValue) }}
    >
      <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
      <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
    </Picker>
  )
}
```

I want to know if anyone has worked with Appium and faced this issue or not. And if anyone got any answer.

Thanks for the help.